# Delete mockable android jar in Android

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

In my Android project in Android Studio 2.1 there is a mockable-android-23.jar that is of about 22 MB size.

Is it safe to delete it?

Answer (score 6):

The `mockable-android-23.jar` file is generated by the `mockableAndroidJar` Gradle Task which is run as part of the `test` Gradle Task.

The file is useful to you if you have unit tests in your project in which you're mocking Android classes (by means of the Mockito framework). If this not the case for you, then yes it is safe for you to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any object related to mockable-android-23.jar, delete the jar file is safe.

Comment: how to find this?